# How to get a runtime class of a variable in Kotlin?

Tags: reflection, kotlin

I want to get a reference to a runtime KClass of a variable. I went through documentation on classes and reflection, but the [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html) seems to only explain how to get a static reference to KClass (e.g. `String::class` for `String`)

I need a runtime KClass of a variable. This doesn't seem to compile:

```
fun test(x: Any) {
    val klazz = x::class
}
```

How does one get the `KClass` of `x` in the example above?

Comment: Do you want the erased type without generic info, or the `KClass<T>`

Comment: In this particular use case, yes, erased type without generic info, but feel free to comment on generic info as well

Answer (score 11, accepted):

As said in the [reference](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/reflection.html#interoperability-with-java-reflection), you can use `.javaClass.kotlin` to get `KClass` token of an object. Example:

```
fun printKClass(x: Any) {
    val c = x.javaClass.kotlin
    println(c)
}
```

For any further manipulations with the `KClass`, you should also add [`kotlin-reflect` library](http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jetbrains.kotlin/kotlin-reflect) as a dependency, since the reflection functionality has been moved out of `kotlin-stdlib`.

Answer (score 1):

`x::class` works fine as long you have kotlin-reflect in your classpath.